# How to seperate Mesh completely for material to work properly,

Tags: mesh, materials

I have a windows mesh, it was one single mesh. I created a material and realized it does not work. So i seperated my mesh into 6 different one but the material still acts like it is one single mesh. How do I separate the mesh completely?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, the issue was the origin point of each window, they shared the same one. It works now, once I have corrected them.